# Internet Explorer, ColdFusion and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have a page loading donation information when a name is selected from a list: http://www.prayingpelicanmissions.org/donate#support
It works in every browser except Internet Explorer. Is there an easy edit that will solve the compatibility issue? Or do I need to figure something else out?

The Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#staffName").change( function() {
      var staffName = $(this).val();
        $.get('/ajax/donatestaff.cfm', {"staffName": staffName}, function(data) {
        $('#staffresult').html(data);   
      });       
    });
  });
</script>
```

The ColdFusion Div

```
<div id="staffresult" style="margin-top:2%;">
  <cfif isDefined("url.staffName")>
    <cfinclude template="ajax/donatestaff.cfm">
  </cfif>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance you can provide.

EDIT: The page just goes blank when you select a name

---

**SOLUTION: Removed CFTOOLTIPS**

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: In IE9 if I select a name I get redirected to what appears to be a blank page.  The html source is this:  <script id="_yui_eu_dr" defer="true" src="//:"></script>

Comment: Upvoted for the name, Praying Pelicans.

Comment: I see my upvote was nullified by a downvote.  Must be an Atheist Albatross or something out there.

Comment: thanks, Dan. it's definitely an interesting name

Answer (score 2):

The donatestaff page is returning a lot of HTML, including all of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */_cf_loadingtexthtml="<img alt=' ' src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'/>";
_cf_contextpath="";
_cf_ajaxscriptsrc="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax";
_cf_jsonprefix='//';
_cf_clientid='5F9D4743F573B3FB1E5DA62CDDD1008D';/* ]]> */</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/container/container-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cftooltip.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/yui/yui.css" />
```

The file `yahoo-dom-event.js` is most likely causing the error in MSIE.

Dan pointed out that MSIE redirects to a blank page with this code: `<script id="_yui_eu_dr" defer="true" src="//:"></script>`. Doing a search for `_yui_eu_dr` turned up some bugs related to YUI (Yahoo's JS library). Which made me check the source of `donatestaff.cfm`.

Can you change that page to not use `CFFORM` (**EDIT**) or any CF UI tags (**/EDIT**)? That should get rid of those JS and CSS files.

Comment: There's no cfform on the page

Comment: Ok, are there any CF UI controls on that page? Unless that code is hard-coded, something from CF is adding it all to the page.

Comment: The only thing out of the normal realm of ColdFusion would be a couple of cfcharts and some cftooltips

Comment: If they're on that donatestaff.cfm page, try removing them and see if the ajax call loads in MSIE.

Comment: THAT'S WHAT IT WAS! THE CFTOOLTIPS! AHHH! You guy's rock. Thanks!

Comment: Given how easy it is to add a tooltip with html only, I've never actually looked at the cftootip tag.